# How can I change the bulbs in this light fixture?

Tags: bulb

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to open this light fixture up to change the bulbs.  Help, please!
[image]

Comment: First you get 500 liberal arts majors, then you get 200 business majors...

Answer (score 11):

Often times the lower round spindle piece of the lamp will screw off. Then the lower metal parts can be lowered down along with the glass pieces to permit access to the bulbs.

Comment: You stole my comment. +1